# Bootstrap datepicker disappear by itself when a date is selected

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, joomla3.0

I'am implementing bootstrap datepicker (i'am using this one : https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) with bootstrap 2.3.2. When the datepicker is open and then i choose a date, then the input field disappear by itself.

I don't find what's going on. There is the code used :

```
jQuery('.input-append.date').datepicker({
  orientation: "bottom auto"
});
```

I'am loading before the files bootstrap-datepicker.css and bootstrap-datepicker.js

In HTML page i have that :

```
<div class="input-append date">
                <input type="text" class="span2" name="poll_time_to_live" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy"><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-grid-view-2 "></i></span>
            </div>
```

I have others scripts loaded before : jquery upload, markitup.js, caret.js, atwho.js

Do-you have an idea ?

Thanks by advance

Comment: may be you used an option `autoclose:true` in your code, which closes the datepicker after date is selected. and better show the code.

Comment: I have added code to my first message

Comment: Try using `autoclose:false` when creating the datepicker

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to replicate the problem

```js
jQuery('.input-append.date').datepicker({
    orientation: "bottom auto"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="input-append date">
  <input type="text" class="span2" name="poll_time_to_live" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy">
  <span class="add-on">
    <i class="icon-grid-view-2 "></i>
</span>

</div>
```

It may have to do with custom css or other javascript getting in the way. Try upgrading your plugins to the most recent versions of themselves and see if that fixes anything. If not, then try a different datepicker. Like https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/